# How do I insulate the floor under my shed?

Tags: insulation, vapor-barrier

I have a shed that has a wood floor laying on a steel frame, which is laying on some tiles on the bare earth. I would say there's roughly 30cm of clearance between the dirt and the floor boards. I want to add some insulation, and I'm wondering what put under there. I'm assuming I need some kind of plastic sheet to stop moisture, and some sort of isolating material like rock wool. Does the moisture barrier go on the bottom, with the rock wool between the floorboards and the barrier, or do I place the barrier on top, exposing the rock wool to the earth? If there's an aluminum film on the rock wool, does it go up or down, or do I need a different material entirely?

Comment: Laying on tiles? Those must be some really thick tiles... mine is on bricks and cinder blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need a separate vapor barrier. What you'll want to do (since the bottom doesn't touch the ground) is put regular faced batts in, with the kraft paper on the bottom side. That's both a vapor barrier and the easier install method.

Putting plastic on the ground under the shed can't hurt, but isn't necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately, batts is not available over here. I can find something similar, but it has a thin layer of aluminum film on one side, like this: http://bendit.nl/shop/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/rockwool-133.jpg Is this also a vapor barrier, and safe to put on the bare earth?

Comment: I wouldn't put foil on the ground. If you don't have faced batts, I would just stuff what you can inside and staple maybe 5-6 mil plastic to hold it in